# Instagram and Node - Error: APISubscriptionError: Invalid "client_id" and/or "client_secret."

Tags: node.js, instagram-api

```
ig.use({
  access_token: 'foo',
  client_id: 'bar',
  client_secret: 'foo'
});

app.get('/tag/:tag', function (req, res) {
  ig.tag_media_recent(req.params.tag, function(err, medias, pagination, remaining, limit) {
    io.sockets.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
    res.json(medias);
  });
});

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
});

ig.add_tag_subscription('brazil', 'http://e1488494.ngrok.io/?tag=brazil', function(err, result, remaining, limit){
  console.log(err);
  err.retry();
});
```

Im using instagram-node lib. But when i start the server its displaying this error. I change the url but not work.

```
[Error: APISubscriptionError: Invalid "client_id" and/or     "client_secret."]
code: 400,
error_type: 'APISubscriptionError',
error_message: 'Invalid "client_id" and/or "client_secret."',
retry: [Function]
```

Comment: is that the access token, client id and client secret you used when you launched? if so it makes sense.. foo, bar and foo are not valid

Comment: these values ​​are example only